Issues with debugging client and server together on VSCode
I'm doing an AngularCLI and Express project on VSCode and I want to debug a client file and a server file.
Here is how my project is set up and which files I would like to debug (highlighted in blue) Click here.
Here's the launch.json file where I set up the multi debug configuration:
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "name": "nodemon",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
      "request": "launch",
      "restart": true,
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node"
    },
    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/"
    },
    {
      "name": "ng test",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: test",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html"
    }
  ]
}

Now, the problem here is when the server file is attached to the debugger, because as output I get:
C:\desktop copy\NEW SHARED FOLDER\BeQuick\BeQuick> cmd /C "set "NODE_OPTIONS= --require "c:/Users/sitis/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js"  --inspect-publish-uid=http" && set "VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS=:::{"inspectorIpc":"\\\\.\\pipe\\node-cdp.2264-c4fb6d73-24.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"C:\\Users\\sitis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\node-debug-callback-7a7a7c65d78e662a"}" && C:\Users\sitis\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd .\server.js "
Debugger attached.
[nodemon] 3.1.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `ng serve .\server.js`
Debugger attached.
Error: Invalid values:
  Argument: project, Given: ".\\server.js", Choices: "BeQuick"
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I think this problem appears because I configured the server file wrongly. Also, the server file is not used in Server Side Rendering. But I cannot find a solution for my main issue.
Any help would be appreciated!

Any ideas on where the problem lays?

Please answer me... at least give me a tip on how to solve this problem.
